# Paypal IPN on my desktop PC?

Tags: paypal-ipn

I have a PC running 24 x 7 .....all the code examples I've seen relate to deploying a paypal listener on a php server.

Is it possible to deploy a Paypal IPN listener on a home office PC running Windows 10?

The ultimate goal is to update MS access (on the same PC) with data taken from Paypal IPN.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't set up a local PHP server using WAMP (or equivalent) and just have it constantly running?

Comment: none...other than i hadn't thought of it (hence posing the question)...i'll follow that line of enquiry up :-)